# How to insert the txt.file string into MYSQL using python

Tags: python, mysql, oracle

I have a text file which contains several character string this below:

```
0546afwq,
5fj532gs,
1824t4sa,
sq234312
```

[image]

Now I would like to import this .txt file to SQL database named TV by using Python and SQL, and create a table ADMIN, add the TXT_results column (varchar2 type).

This is what I tried this far:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('account/password@db')

cur = conn.cursor()

if conn:

print("data base has already connected")

with open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\result.txt') as infile:

for line in infile:

    data = line.split(",")
    query = ("insert INTO admin(txt_results) VALUES (%s)")
    cur.execute(query, data)

    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

---

And got the following error code :
`"ORACLE] ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"`

Could anybody help me to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Porperly paste your code and post the full error traceback. It shows you which line of code failed and makes debugging errors a lot easier.

Comment: Your subject line says you are using MySQL, but your presented code says you are using oracle.  And you have tagged both oracle and MySQL.  Regardless of corporate ownership, oracle != mysql.  So which is it? Are you trying to use oracle constructs against a mysql database? If so, that simply will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For starters TXT_results is not defined in your db I assume what you wanted in place of that is a place holder for line which would be %s but you also should format the values of the line you read (separate with commas by field), it's also always good to specify the columns you're inserting for transparency